# push notification got error

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded the sample application for Push Notification Module (I am basing this on the [push notifications sample app](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#adavanced-topics)),  and when i start worklight server i've got error  `" Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight bundles."`,then i import "mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar" and try start worklight server again,i'm got error
`" FWLSE4002E: Failed to connect to MYSQL database : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure`

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
[2013-04-11 09:05:33] FWLST0011E: ====== Worklight Project module_07_05_NativeAPIForAndroidPush-project-customization failed to start: Connection refused: connect"

I've try search on google but don't got answer, anybody help me regarding this issue ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the MySQL Connector/J file under the server\lib folder. You also need to update worklight.properties with your MySQL settings if you plan on using MySQL.

You should go through the Worklight Getting Started material, [where SQL adapter development and setup](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development) is explained and demonstrated.

Connect to your MySQL server and make sure that there is a Worklight database. Also make sure that there is a "Worklight" user, and that this user has permissions to access the "Worklight" database.

Also make sure that in your adapter's XML, you specify the username and password:

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
    <user>myUsername</user>
    <password>myPassword</password> 
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

Comment: Thanks mr Idan Adar,i've put mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar under server\lib ,and add to properties-> java build path->libraries.My worklight.properties update like wl.db.type=MYSQL 
wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Worklight wl.db.username=Worklight
wl.db.password=Worklightsso.cleanup.taskFrequencyInSeconds=5
ssl.keystore.path=conf/default.keystore 
ssl.keystore.type=jks 
ssl.keystore.password=worklight 
but I still get the error,What should I do now?

Comment: Please don't paste code-related text in Comments. See my edited Answered.

Comment: ok,thanks you,i'll review it again,could you see this link to help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921574/cant-run-ibm-worklight-app-in-real-device-android